# iOS 7 UITableView issue - attempting to set a swipe to delete cell when we already have one

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios7

I am seeing an issue with iOS 7. When I bring my UITableView in edit mode - I noticed that I can tap on multiple red "-" button to bring "Delete" option on multiple cells. When this happens I see below warning in console logs. Also, after some operations I am not able to tap on the "-" button.

Works fine in iOS 6.

Is this an iOS7 bug? Do anyone know the workaround for this?

**attempting to set a swipe to delete cell when we already have one....that doesn't seem good`**

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {
    return (self.isEditMode) ? YES : NO;
}


- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {
    return (iIndexPath.row !=0 && self.isEditMode) ? UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete : UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an issue with iOS 7 and shall be fixed in next iOS release. Have reported this to Apple.

Comment: now I am using Xcode 5.1.1 , still  I have the same issue

Answer (score 4):

I had this same bug until I changed my method to this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //remove the deleted object from your data source.
        //If your data source is an NSMutableArray, do this
        [self.array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

}
```

I hope this is helpful to somebody else.

Comment: Upvote for a working solution!  Thanks for this... I was pulling my hair out for an hour trying to figure out why my tableview was going bonkers in edit mode.